# Angular Material mat-form-field doesnt render css styles

Tags: angular, angular-material

Sometimes, not always, browser renders input fields without css styles, like border on this screenshot. No errors. Does someone know how to fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found out that applying a **::ng-deep** to a component element through related css-file can cause a changing around all components inside app. So I wrapped current component in a single css class, and modified related css correspondingly.

```css
   .my-component ::ng-deep .mat-form-field-underline {
      display: none;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="my-component">
    ..
    </div>
```